# 'Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function' when integrating Firebase to Vue.js 2

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I get this error when inspecting

```
Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function.
```

Used dependencies:

```
"vuefire": "^3.0.0-alpha.2"

"firebase": "^9.0.2"
```

my `db.js` file:

```
import * as Firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "x***************************",
      authDomain: "a**********.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "f****demo-****",
      storageBucket: "f**********.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "2***********",
      appId: "1:**********:web:2**************"
});
export const db = initializeApp(firebaseApp.firestore());
```

How the error get solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v9 of the Firebase SDK the API surface changed to using modular, tree-shakeable code. Expect pretty much every piece of documentation or example code you see to have been written for v8 or older Firebase SDK versions that need updating.

Read more [about migrating here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

For your specific case, you need to use the `getFirestore()` method, passing in the relevant `FirebaseApp` instance:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
```

Although, because this is the default unnamed instance, you can also just use:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

export const db = getFirestore();
```

Comment: It is really good answer.It worked.Then I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection').Should I initiate a document instance in db.js?

Comment: To get a collection, you'll need to use `import { collection } from "firebase/firestore";` and `collection(db, 'collectionName')`. The [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) cover the steps in more detail.